# Putting information into model from radio button and getting value back out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the code for the view:

```
  <h3>Reviews:</h3>
<% @restaurant.reviews.reverse.each do |review| %>
posted by: <%= review.poster %><br />
written: <%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago<br />
Review: <%= review.rating %><br />
<%= review.article %><br /><br />
<% end %>

<hr />
<h3>Submit new review:</h3>
<%= form_tag :action => 'review', :id => @restaurant do %>
<h4>Poster: </h4>
<%= text_field "review", "poster" %>
<h4>Rating:</h4>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating, "1") %>
<%= label_tag(:rating_1, "1") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating, "2") %>
<%= label_tag(:rating_2, "2") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating, "3") %>
<%= label_tag(:rating_3, "3") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating, "4") %>
<%= label_tag(:rating_4, "4") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:rating, "5") %>
<%= label_tag(:rating_5, "5") %>

<!--<strong>Date: </strong><%= datetime_select "review", "date" %><br /><br />-->
<h4>Review:</h4><br />
<%= text_area "review", "article", :rows => 5 %><br />
<%= submit_tag "Review" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the methods I think are relevant in the controller:

```
  def review
    @restaurant.reviews << Review.create!(review_params)
    redirect_to :action => "show", :id => params[:id]
  end

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:poster, :rating, :article)
  end
```

Back in the view where I have `<%= review.rating %>` nothing shows up for that. When I submit the code I don't get an error so I was assuming the value was being submitted with the form. But maybe it's not and I'm missing something there?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1** Here is the log. On the third line it looks like the rating is being captured but not within the reviews param.

```
Started POST "/restaurants/review?id=marco-luca" for 71.206.170.86 at 2014-09-08 12:13:49 +0000                                                                                                                                        
Processing by RestaurantsController#review as HTML                                                                                                                                                                                     
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FmYCRjCb4794QcXzoPkqRAdLxr2pJQPPaAErsgYXOSA=", "review"=>{"poster"=>"jody", "article"=>"liked it!"}, "rating"=>"4", "commit"=>"Review", "id"=>"marco-luca"}                         
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                                                                         
  Restaurant Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"  WHERE "restaurants"."slug" = 'marco-luca'  ORDER BY "restaurants"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                              
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  SQL (9.5ms)  INSERT INTO "reviews" ("article", "created_at", "poster", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["article", "liked it!"], ["created_at", "2014-09-08 12:13:49.034664"], ["poster", "jody"], ["updated_a
t", "2014-09-08 12:13:49.034664"]]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   (21.1ms)  COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "reviews" SET "restaurant_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "reviews"."id" = 16  [["restaurant_id", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-09-08 12:13:49.081358"]]                                                            
   (1.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Can you post the `log` generated while `submitting the form`?

Comment: I'm guessing if I can add rating to the review hash then that should get it to work. But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by changing the radio buttons to `<%= radio_button("review", "rating", "1") %>`

Instead of `<%= radio_button_tag(:rating, "1") %>`